# Obtener el texto dentro de la etiqueta <b>

Tags: php, regex

Tengo una cadena con información de este tipo:

```
 $texto = "cualquiercosa<b>contenido</b>cualquiercosa";
 $resultado = preg_split("<b></b>",$str)
```

Sin embargo, el resultado no trae el texto entre las etiquetas. ¿Podrían ayudarme en cómo debe ser la expresión regular?

Comment: ¿Por qué habría de traer el texto si no es una expresión regular válida, ni está cerca de serlo? ... ¿Cuál es el objetivo? ¿Extraer sólo el contenido de texto dentro de cada etiqueta `<b>`? ¿Probaste utilizando DOM?

Comment: Solo quiero el texto que esta entre esas etiquetas. Desde el DOM no puedo, porque la información provienen con PHP y quiero tratar primero el texto antes de imprimir en el Documento.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No deberías usar expresiones regulares para procesar HTML. Tan sólo un pequeño cambio en el HTML haría que tu regex falle. Un espacio de más, un cambio en los atributos del tag, un comentario, o estructuras más complejas, harían que hasta un regex gigantesco no siga las reglas.

Es muy sencillo procesar HTML con **[DOM](http://php.net/manual/es/book.dom.php)**, son las herramientas que están pensadas para eso.

Simplemente se genera el DOM así:

```php
$html = 'cualquiercosa<b>contenido</b>cualquiercosa';

//Generar el DOM
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_COMPACT | LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_NONET);
```

Y podemos obtener todos los `<b>`:

```php
//Obtener todos los tags <B>
$b_nodelist = $dom->getElementsByTagName('b');
```

Para luego iterar sobre la lista de resultados, obteniendo el texto dentro de cada etiqueta (sin etiquetas):

```php
//Bucle para cada <b>
foreach ($b_nodelist as $b) {

    //Obtener el contenido de texto del tag
    $texto = $b->textContent;

    echo "\n\nContenido del B:\n" . $texto;    // => contenido
}
```

Resultado:

```
Contenido del B:
contenido
```

Demo:

[<kbd>Ver la demo en 3v4l.org</kbd>](https://3v4l.org/ZZVPd)

Comment: Gracias por la información.